# Embedding Native Android Activity in React Native

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, reactjs, react-native

I am making tab bar in android in react native using this library

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tabs

I have to open native android activity in one of the page.
Can you please let me know how to embed android activity in react native so that tabs will be visible all the time.